# Has any lander or rover (besides Huygens) used a flood-light for photography?

Tags: imaging, photography

I've asked about the flood-light that apparently was included on the [Huygens lander](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huygens_(spacecraft)) in the question [Did the Huygens lander have a flood-light for photography? Was it used?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/24272/12102).

Have there been any other landers or rovers that have been at least launched into space which were equipped with flood-lights for photography/imaging?

**note:** I'm not asking about laser scanners. This is about lights which are somewhat uncollimated and illuminate an extended area so that cameras can record images in low light levels.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. The **MAHLI** (Mars Hand Lens Imager) instrument on Mars Science Laboratory (also known as Curiosity) has both white visible light LEDs and ultraviolet LEDs for nighttime imaging and promotion of UV fluorescence, respectively.

[image]

> The MAHLI includes two sets of two white light LEDs to permit nighttime imaging. Each pair can be independently commanded on/off. MAHLI also has two ultraviolet (365 nm) LEDs to look for materials that fluoresce under longwave UV illumination. The UV LEDs are included on an exploratory, "best efforts" basis and are not a calibrated investigative tool. The MSL Project is required to accommodate night operations of MAHLI, but thermal and power constraints might preclude more than just occasional night-time operation of the instrument and the robotic arm.

- MAHLI Instruments Page, [courtesy JPL](https://msl-scicorner.jpl.nasa.gov/Instruments/MAHLI/).

- The four white LEDs produced by Avago Technologies from their HSMW-10x series ([Product Data Sheet](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1855424.pdf))
- The two UV LEDs are produced by Nichia (NSHU550B's).

These were first used on 22 January 2013:

[image]

([NASA Press Release](https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/msl/news/msl20130124.html))