# Are there both "lake" and "sea" designations on Titan? Officially or otherwise?

Tags: planetary-science, titan, cassini, huygens-lander

@TomSpilker's [excellent answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/38099/12102) to *How (the heck) do they know some lakes on Titan are 100 meters deep?* says at the very end:

> As far as the *lakes* (smaller than the seas) go, as the sources you cite state, the last close *Cassini* flyby of Titan used this technique to measure depths of some of these lakes. Some researchers had proposed that the lakes are considerably shallower than the seas. This experiment put an end to that idea!

Are there both "lake" and "sea" designations on Titan? Officially or otherwise?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [International Astronomical Union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Astronomical_Union) is the most official source on this matter.

[Among other surface features](https://planetarynames.wr.usgs.gov/Page/TITAN/target) on Titan the IAU recognizes [81 lakes](https://planetarynames.wr.usgs.gov/SearchResults?target=TITAN&featureType=Lacus,%20lac%C5%ABs) (*lacūs*, "small dark plains with discrete, sharp boundaries") of 5km to 240km diameter (median 36km), and three larger [seas](https://planetarynames.wr.usgs.gov/SearchResults?target=TITAN&featureType=Mare,%20maria) (*maria*, "large expanses of dark materials thought to be hydrocarbons"):

Kraken Mare, 1170km in diameter; Ligeia Mare, 500km in diameter, and Punga Mare, 380km in diameter.

The IAU's Working Group for Planetary System Nomenclature has chosen [themes or naming conventions for each class of feature on Titan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planetary_nomenclature#Titan); the *lacūs* are named for Earth lakes (similarly shaped ones, preferably), and the *maria* are named for mythical sea creatures.